# Including *.png, *.pdf, compiling with dvipdfmx gives `Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!`

Tags: graphics, dvipdfmx

I'm trying to compile a paper, using `elsarticle`. I need to include some images, however, I have them only in `*.png` or `*.pdf` (converted from *.png using `convert file.png file.pdf`), not in *.eps format.

I think I tried almost everything, but none of these things seemed to work properly.

1) Using `natwidth` and `natheight` with `*.png` file, gives empty image (I can't see the image, huh):

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% FOR TEST ONLY
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Test}
\author{Test Test \corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
\address{Institute of Computer Science}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{test@gmail.com}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\blinddescription
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

\blindmathpaper

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics [natwidth=515,natheight=377]{image.png}
\caption{test}
\label{img:fig1}
\label{tvdmd}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

2) Using `natwidth` and `natheight` AND `scale` with `*.png` file, the same as above:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% FOR TEST ONLY
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Test}
\author{Test Test \corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
\address{Institute of Computer Science}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{test@gmail.com}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\blinddescription
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

\blindmathpaper

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics [scale=0.5, natwidth=515,natheight=377]{image.png}
\caption{test}
\label{img:fig1}
\label{tvdmd}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

3) Using `*.pdf` instead of `*.png` (can't see the image):

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% FOR TEST ONLY
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Test}
\author{Test Test \corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
\address{Institute of Computer Science}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{test@gmail.com}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\blinddescription
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

\blindmathpaper

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics [scale=0.5, natwidth=515,natheight=377]{image.pdf}
\caption{test}
\label{img:fig1}
\label{tvdmd}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

4) Using `*.pdf` WITHOUT `natwidth` and `natheight` gives: `LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in tvdmd.pdf (no BoundingBox).`

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% FOR TEST ONLY
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Test}
\author{Test Test \corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
\address{Institute of Computer Science}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{test@gmail.com}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\blinddescription
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

\blindmathpaper

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics [scale=0.5]{tvdmd.pdf}
\caption{test}
\label{img:fig1}
\label{tvdmd}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Moreover, in each of the above situations, I got some extra additional errors, every time (1)-4)):

```
elsarticle-template.dvi -> elsarticle-template.pdf
[1
** WARNING ** Unparsed material at end of special ignored.

Current input buffer is -->! systemdict /pdfmark known{userdict /?pdfmark sys...<--

** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(72, 720)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin [/Producer (dvips + Distiller)/Title ()/Subje..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin [/Producer (dvips + Distiller)/Title ()/Subject ()/Cre...<<
** WARNING ** Unparsed material at end of special ignored.

Current input buffer is -->! /DvipsToPDF{72.27 mul Resolution div} def/PDFToD...<--

** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(72, 720)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin /product where{pop product(Distiller)search{p..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin /product where{pop product(Distiller)search{pop pop po...<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.S end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.S end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.R end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.R end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (page.1) cvn /DEST pdf..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (page.1) cvn /DEST pdfmark end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(133.768, 667.198)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin [/Count -0/Dest (section.1) cvn/Title (Introd..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin [/Count -0/Dest (section.1) cvn/Title (Introduction) /...<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(133.768, 667.198)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin [/PageMode /UseOutlines/Page 1/View [/Fit] /D..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin [/PageMode /UseOutlines/Page 1/View [/Fit] /DOCVIEW pd...<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(133.768, 667.198)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin [ {Catalog}<<>> /PUT pdfmark end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin [ {Catalog}<<>> /PUT pdfmark end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(133.768, 667.198)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.S end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.S end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(133.768, 667.198)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin 18 H.A end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin 18 H.A end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(133.768, 667.198)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (Doc-Start) cvn /DEST ..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (Doc-Start) cvn /DEST pdfmark e..<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(133.768, 667.198)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.S end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.S end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(133.768, 667.198)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin 18 H.A end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin 18 H.A end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(133.768, 667.198)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (cnote.1) cvn /DEST pd..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (cnote.1) cvn /DEST pdfmark end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(133.768, 212.725)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.S end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.S end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(133.768, 212.725)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin 18 H.A end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin 18 H.A end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(133.768, 212.725)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (section.1) cvn /DEST ..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (section.1) cvn /DEST pdfmark e..<<
][2
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="2" position="(72, 720)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin /product where{pop product(Distiller)search{p..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin /product where{pop product(Distiller)search{pop pop po...<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="2" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.S end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.S end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="2" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.R end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.R end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="2" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (page.2) cvn /DEST pdf..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (page.2) cvn /DEST pdfmark end<<
][3
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="3" position="(72, 720)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin /product where{pop product(Distiller)search{p..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin /product where{pop product(Distiller)search{pop pop po...<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="3" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.S end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.S end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="3" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.R end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.R end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="3" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (page.3) cvn /DEST pdf..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (page.3) cvn /DEST pdfmark end<<
][4
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="4" position="(72, 720)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin /product where{pop product(Distiller)search{p..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin /product where{pop product(Distiller)search{pop pop po...<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="4" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.S end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.S end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="4" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.R end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.R end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="4" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (page.4) cvn /DEST pdf..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (page.4) cvn /DEST pdfmark end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="4" position="(317.305, 287.671)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.S end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.S end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="4" position="(317.305, 287.671)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.R end"
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.R end<<
** WARNING ** Unknown token "SDict"
** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="4" position="(317.305, 287.671)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "ps:SDict begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (figure.1) cvn /DEST p..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (figure.1) cvn /DEST pdfmark en.<<
]
39247 bytes written
```

I know these are just warnings, not errors, but it results in corrupted pdf file. I compile it like this:

```
latex elsarticle-template.tex
dvipdfm elsarticle-template.dvi
```

**And of course, I know that using `pdflatex` everything works like a charm, but I NEED to compile it that way (since the journal I want to submit to uses this). Any ideas?**

Comment: Why don't you convert `*.pdf` to `*.ps`?

Comment: Can't you compile with `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Bernard: I explained at the end of my post ...

Comment: @Werner: after converting, it still gives me `Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!`

Comment: @yak: So you tried converting ALL graphics to `.ps` or `.eps` and compiling with LaTeX (instead of pdfLaTeX) and this still failed? Then you're doing something wrong... what did you use to convert the graphics?

Comment: Not even xelatex?

Comment: @yak: Note that after converting, you should just use `\includegraphics{<file>}` *without* the file extension. LaTeX will automatically use the `.ps` or `.eps` version.

Comment: @Werner: Here's what I did step by step: http://pastie.org/10892141 and no success

Comment: @yak: Then your problem is that you haven't removed the file extensions from your `\includegraphics` command. You need to let [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) decide on the file to include depending on the compilation technique/driver (latex, or pdflatex). Alternatively, force TeX to use the `.ps` or `.eps` graphic file by using those extensions exclusively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using dvipdfm you will have to add the suitable driver information to all packages as normally dvips is assumed. So try something like

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipdfmx}{graphicx} %or dvipdfm depending on the tex system
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}
```

Comment: This actually solved my problem, thank you so much!