# No Diagram Shows up when Using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to learn to use TikZ and I have copied and pasted the following from https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf:

```
\documentclass{article} % say
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
We are working on
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
        \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}.
\end{document}
```

(I added an extra line between each line in this question, which I did not add in TeXnicCenter.)

When I load the PDF (using SumatraPDF), I get the words "We are working on", but no picture. However, the text is moved down as though there is a picture, and the space where the picture should be flashes blue as if it were loading if it is open while I am updating the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Everything is fine on my end. The code is compilable. Probably close the viewer and open the pdf directly. It can be a synctex issue. Clearing the temporary files would serve too.

Comment: @azetina Changing LaTeX => DVI => PDF to LaTeX => PDF did work, but I don't know if that is what you were suggesting (I don't know how to open the pdf directly and I don't know if this is equivalent).  I also don't know if converting to DVI in the middle is important; is it?

Comment: To open automatically, you will need to edit the compilers settings to open in an external viewer.

Comment: Converting to DVI in the middle is important. I don't mean that you need to do this. But whether or not you do it is important. In some cases, your code will not compile correctly if you do this; in other cases, it won't compile correctly if you do. In most cases, it will compile correctly either way. The difference is the *engine* used to compile the TeX source. Probably, your editor uses pdfTeX by default for the TeX -> PDF pathway and TeX by default for the TeX -> DVI pathway. It then uses another programme to compile the PDF from the DVI. Read the console/log to see what's going wrong.

Comment: @cfr I have looked up the errors in my Build Output.  It led me to <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316913/including-png-pdf-compiling-with-dvipdfmx-gives-interpreting-ps-code-fail/316917> which led me to the solution of adding
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipdfm}{graphicx}
at the beginning of the preamble.
So that worked; thanks!  Of course now I have to choose whether to convert directly to PDF or to put that line in the preamble... any help?

Comment: I would compile directly to PDF unless you have specific reason not to. At least, that's my approach and, when I teach LaTeX to beginners, I recommend using pdfTeX.

Comment: I have put your example in Overleaf and it works, you can [check it here](https://www.overleaf.com/6335622cgxzmb#). Probably your local installation is not ok.

Answer (score 1):

One solution was to change the file conversion from

LaTeX => DVI => PDF

to

LaTeX => PDF;

Another was to add

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipdfm}{graphicx}
```

to the beginning of the preamble.